# Sources of 'removeObjectAtIndex:'

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a crash in

`-[__NSArrayM removeObjectAtIndex:] + 262`

However my code does not use `removeObjectAtIndex:`. Are there any other functions which might call `removeObjectAtIndex:` internally?

My guess is `replaceObjectAtIndex:` which I use.

Also, is there some documentation source where I can get information like this?

here is the complete stack trace:

```
Thread : Fatal Exception: NSRangeException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001860fe59c __exceptionPreprocess + 132
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x000000019685c0e4 objc_exception_throw + 60
2  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000185fe362c -[__NSArrayM removeObjectAtIndex:]
3  Musixmatch                     0x0000000100b9da24 +[MyController updateMessage:] + 1011504
4  Musixmatch                     0x0000000100b95dc8 -[MyAPICalls sendNewMessage:] + 979668
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000196ea13ac _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000196ea136c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000196eab4c0 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1216
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000196ea4474 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 132
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000196ead224 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 664
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000196eae75c _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 108
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x000000019707d2e4 _pthread_wqthread + 816
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x000000019707cfa8 start_wqthread + 4
```

So the last method called from the app is `updateMessage:`. Update message itself only has a `objectAtIndex:`. It then makes a call to two methods in other classes. But if they were causing the crash, I believe they should have been included in the stack trace.

Comment: Please post the complete stacktrace.  Alternatively look at it yourself.  It will tell you what called it.

Comment: Try looking at the call stack to find the last line executed in your own code that threw the exception and fix that instead. Adding a exception breakpoint might also help.

Comment: Are you using replace object inside a loop?

Comment: OK, now symbolicate the crash log and whatever was `[MyController updateMessage:] + 1011504` is the code that is calling the method directly.  It's almost certainly using the wrong index value.

Comment: Can you post the code for you `updateMessage` method please

Comment: Use exception breakpoint for where your problem is occurring

Comment: You are referring to index which is out of bounds in updateMessage method e.g., consider your array size is 3, but you refer to the 4th object. So best would be to check if whether the index below count. Or post your updateMessage method code

Comment: if you are not manipulating indexes, maybe you are trying to modify data from another thread. In that case you should use the dispatch_async or use blocks to send back your operation to the proper thread. just an idea..

Comment: Same problem here. Stack trace line number indicates a call to `objectAtIndex`, not `removeObjectAtIndex`.